# Angular5 Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular5

Hello I want to display a list of users data but I have put a condition on that if user data is greater than 0 then display otherwise not with help of **length** property in `*ngIf`, so my issue when I use this it gets error like `Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`,So please anyone help me.
I also show same question on angular2 version but didn't help much.Here is my view.

```
<div *ngIf="(studentListData | filter).length == 0">
   <h3>Sorry ..!data not found</h3>
</div>

<div *ngIf="(studentListData | filter | filter ).length > 0>
   <tr *ngFor="let student of studentListData | filtter; index as i;">
        // ** here is my td *//
   </tr>
</div>
```

In my component

```
export class studentAllComponet implements OnInit {
  studentListData:any;

getStudentList(){
        let studentList = this.studentService.getAllStudents();
        this.success(studentList)
    }

success(data){
        this.studentListData = data;
        for (var i = 0; i < this.studentListData.length; i++) {
            this.studentListData[i].name = this.studentListData[i].first_name +' '+ this.studentListData[i].last_name;
        }
    }

}
```

In my filter

```
@Pipe({  name: 'filtter' })
export class FiltterPipe implements PipeTransform{
   transform(value: any, args?: any): any {
        if (args != undefined && args != null && args != '') {
            return value.filter(data => (data.name.toLowerCase()).indexOf(args.toLowerCase()) > -1);
        }
        return value;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance..!

Comment: You can use the elvis operator to check for undefined, place ? after any field, doing so would not throw an error like the one you are facing, for e.g do this. <div *ngIf="(studentListData | filter)?.length == 0">

Comment: didn't solve?I used the same but.

Comment: trying creating a plunkr so that we can debug the issue for you. Maybe try a hard refresh first.

Comment: What does your service return? An Observable?

Comment: @SamiAl90  I just save my data in local storage and in  service i get like this  if (localStorage.getItem('students') && localStorage.getItem('students') != '') {
            studentList = {
                code: 200,
                message: "Students List Fetched Successfully",
                data: JSON.stringify(localStorage.getItem('students'))
            }

Answer (score 3):

In your template you can use the [safe navigation operator](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#safe-navigation-operator) '?' before a property access so angular will check for you if it has an object. I guess studentListData is null or not defined by the time your template is rendered.

```
<div *ngIf="(studentListData | filter)?.length == 0">
   <h3>Sorry ..!data not found</h3>
</div>

<div *ngIf="(studentListData | filter | filter )?.length > 0">
   <tr *ngFor="let student of studentListData | filtter; index as i;">
        // ** here is my td *//
   </tr>
</div>
```

Comment: @SamiAI90 I used same before i post the question but the problem is same..

Comment: @SamiAI90 means my filter pipe code paste on comment section?

Comment: @Kansara no, edit your question and add the pipes and components code please. You could also create a stackblitz. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-slshz6

Answer (score 0):

If your studentService returns an observable, I would use subscribe to get the result from it and manipulate the result in the subscribe method:

```
getStudentList(){
  this.studentService
    .getAllStudents()
    .subscribe((data: any) => {
      data.forEach((d) => {
        d.name = d.first_name + ' ' + d.last_name
      })
      this.studentListData = data;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think , you can handle this in the TypeSript only. No need to change in HTML code.

In your component you can check, whether  the studentList is generated empty or not.

---

```
export class studentAllComponet implements OnInit {
studentListData:any;

getStudentList(){
let studentList = this.studentService.getAllStudents();
**if(studentList === undefined){
  alert('Student List is empty');
  return[];
}**
else{
    this.success(studentList)
    }
}

success(data){
    this.studentListData = data;
    for (var i = 0; i < this.studentListData.length; i++) {
        this.studentListData[i].name = this.studentListData[i].first_name +' '+ this.studentListData[i].last_name;
    }
}

}
```

And now you no need to use any filter in HTML.

Answer (score 0):

A very simple solution:

In your component file, you can initialize the **studentListData** with an empty array like this

```
export class studentAllComponet implements OnInit {
    studentListData:any = [];
```

Now, this will take care of **undefined** issue since you always have an array, its just that it is empty at the beginning.

Hope this helps. Happy Coding :)